# AngularJS - spell checker in german

Tags: angularjs, spell-checking

I have found a spell checker in english:

[spellchecker english](https://github.com/JeffJin/spellchecker)

Is there also one in german?

Comment: This question should be closed. Questions regarding finding libraries or programs are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [JavaScript SpellCheck](http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/Translations).
It supports a wide variety of languages including German.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the application i developed, I used the key-value paired JS file for all required languages. Those translations i am received from business or i translated English to XXX language using google translator & verified those from the business. Once you have it then it is very easy to apply it into application using angular translation service.